# In Rust, what is the proper way to replicate Python's "repeat" parameter in itertools.product?

Tags: python, rust, rust-itertools

In Python, I can do:

```
from itertools import product

k = 3
for kmer in product("AGTC", repeat=k):
    print(kmer)
```

In Rust, I can force the behavior of `k=3` by:

```
#[macro_use] extern crate itertools;

for kmer in iproduct!("AGTC".chars(), "AGTC".chars(), "AGTC".chars()){
    println!("{:?}", kmer);
}
```

But what if I wanted `k=4` or `k=5`?

Comment: Can you explain whether you really need to yield tuples? With an argument `k` only known in run-time, you cannot produce Rust tuples of `k` values.

Comment: I don't necessarily need tuples; strings would be preferable. I'm eventually going to be searching longer strings for these kmers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing a proper generalisation for any type for any k would be hard because the return type could be tuples of any size. As you want to work only on `String`, it's quite easier: [playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=03ff026bf57d73dcc9c6abe62eeecc69&version=undefined)

```
fn kproduct(seq: String, k: u32) -> Vec<String> {
    match k {
        0 => vec![],
        1 => seq.chars().map(|c| c.to_string()).collect(),
        2 => iproduct!(seq.chars(), seq.chars()).map(|(a, b)| format!("{}{}", a, b)).collect(),
        _ => iproduct!(kproduct(seq.clone(), k - 1), seq.chars()).map(|(a, b)| format!("{}{}", a, b)).collect(),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm answering this question after 4 years both because the accepted answer is too convoluted, and due to the fact that Python's `itertools.product` is a generic function (whereas the accepted answer works only for `String`s).
Moreover, notice that the `kproduct` function defined in the accepted answer is recursive, and [Rust doesn't guarantee tail-call optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59257543/when-is-tail-recursion-guaranteed-in-rust).

Using the third-party [itertools](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.1/itertools/) crate, we can define a `product_repeat` function in two ways: either by defining a standard top-level function, or by adding a `ProductRepeat` trait for all `Iterator`s.

This is the top-level function:

```rust
use itertools::{Itertools, MultiProduct};

/// Rust version of Python's itertools.product().
/// It returns the cartesian product of the input iterables, and it is
/// semantically equivalent to `repeat` nested for loops.
///
/// # Arguments
///
/// * `it` - An iterator over a cloneable data structure
/// * `repeat` - Number of repetitions of the given iterator
pub fn product_repeat<I>(it: I, repeat: usize) -> MultiProduct<I>
  where
    I: Iterator + Clone,
    I::Item: Clone {
  std::iter::repeat(it)
    .take(repeat)
    .multi_cartesian_product()
}
```

If you instead prefer augmenting the Iterator trait, you can do it as follows:

```rust
pub trait ProductRepeat: Iterator + Clone
  where Self::Item: Clone {
  fn product_repeat(self, repeat: usize) -> MultiProduct<Self> {
    std::iter::repeat(self)
      .take(repeat)
      .multi_cartesian_product()
  }
}

impl<T: Iterator + Clone> ProductRepeat for T
  where T::Item: Clone {}
```

Here is a demo in the [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fc2c51afff1b9cca9ea006889bcf5a52).