# When is tail recursion guaranteed in Rust?

Tags: recursion, rust, tail-recursion

## C language

In the C programming language, it's easy to have **tail recursion**:

```c
int foo(...) {
    return foo(...);
}
```

Just return as is the return value of the recursive call. It is especially important when this recursion may repeat a thousand or even a million times. It would use a lot of **memory on the stack**.

## Rust

Now, I have a Rust function that might recursively call itself a million times:

```
fn read_all(input: &mut dyn std::io::Read) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    match input.read(&mut [0u8]) {
        Ok (  0) => Ok(()),
        Ok (  _) => read_all(input),
        Err(err) => Err(err),
    }
}
```

(this is a minimal example, the real one is more complex, but it captures the main idea)

Here, the return value of the recursive call is returned as is, but:

**Does it guarantee that the Rust compiler will apply a tail recursion?**

For instance, if we declare some variable that needs to be destroyed like a `std::Vec`, will it be destroyed just before the recursive call (which allows for tail recursion) or after the recursive call returns (which forbids the tail recursion)?

Comment: I believe you are talking about [*tail* recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), you might have better input on your question if you say "tail" instead of "terminal"

Comment: "In C programming language, a terminal recursion is easy to be guaranteed" I'd be surprised if C made any such guarantee.

Comment: [Relevant RFC PR](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1888)

Comment: I think you are mixing tail recursion with tail call optimization. Eg. your C code is tail recursive but it might blow the stack becase it does not guarantee [tail call optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call_optimization)

Comment: BTW Rustaceans often prefer `mut w: impl Write` over `w: &mut dyn Write`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Neither [tail recursion](https://wiki.c2.com/?TailRecursion) (reusing a stack frame for a tail call to the same function) nor [tail call optimization](https://wiki.c2.com/?TailCallOptimization) (reusing the stack frame for a tail call to *any* function) are ever guaranteed by Rust, although the optimizer *may* choose to perform them.

> if we declare some variable that needs to be destroyed

It's my understanding that this is one of the sticking points, as changing the location of destroyed stack variables would be contentious.

See also:

- [Recursive function calculating factorials leads to stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39840663/155423)
- [RFC 81: guaranteed tail call elimination](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/81)
- [RFC 1888: Proper tail calls](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1888)

Answer (score 73):

[Shepmaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59258170/3650362) explains that tail call elimination is merely an optimization, not a guarantee, in Rust. But "never guaranteed" doesn't mean "never happens". Let's take a look at what the compiler does with some real code.

## Does it happen in *this* function?

As of right now, the latest release of Rust available on [Compiler Explorer](https://rust.godbolt.org/) is 1.39, and it does *not* eliminate the tail call in `read_all`.

```
example::read_all:
        push    r15
        push    r14
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 32
        mov     r14, rdx
        mov     r15, rsi
        mov     rbx, rdi
        mov     byte ptr [rsp + 7], 0
        lea     rdi, [rsp + 8]
        lea     rdx, [rsp + 7]
        mov     ecx, 1
        call    qword ptr [r14 + 24]
        cmp     qword ptr [rsp + 8], 1
        jne     .LBB3_1
        movups  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rsp + 16]
        movups  xmmword ptr [rbx], xmm0
        jmp     .LBB3_3
.LBB3_1:
        cmp     qword ptr [rsp + 16], 0
        je      .LBB3_2
        mov     rdi, rbx
        mov     rsi, r15
        mov     rdx, r14
        call    qword ptr [rip + example::read_all@GOTPCREL]
        jmp     .LBB3_3
.LBB3_2:
        mov     byte ptr [rbx], 3
.LBB3_3:
        mov     rax, rbx
        add     rsp, 32
        pop     rbx
        pop     r14
        pop     r15
        ret
        mov     rbx, rax
        lea     rdi, [rsp + 8]
        call    core::ptr::real_drop_in_place
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    _Unwind_Resume@PLT
        ud2
```

Notice this line: `call    qword ptr [rip + example::read_all@GOTPCREL]`. That's the (tail) recursive call. As you can tell from its existence, it was not eliminated.

[Compare this to an equivalent function with an explicit `loop`](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/8HVav3):

```
pub fn read_all(input: &mut dyn std::io::Read) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    loop {
        match input.read(&mut [0u8]) {
            Ok (  0) => return Ok(()),
            Ok (  _) => continue,
            Err(err) => return Err(err),
        }
    }
}
```

which has no tail call to eliminate, and therefore compiles to a function with only one `call` in it (to the computed address of `input.read`).

Oh well. Maybe Rust isn't as good as C. Or is it?

## Does it happen in C?

Here's a tail-recursive function in C that performs a very similar task:

```c
int read_all(FILE *input) {
    char buf[] = {0, 0};
    if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, input))
        return feof(input);
    return read_all(input);
}
```

This should be super easy for the compiler to eliminate. The recursive call is right at the bottom of the function and C doesn't have to worry about running destructors. But nevertheless, [there's that recursive tail call](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/U7V-ud), annoyingly not eliminated:

```
        call    read_all
```

Tail call optimization is not guaranteed to happen in C, either. No compiler I tried would be convinced to turn this into a loop on its own initiative.

Since version 13, clang supports a non-standard `musttail` attribute you can add to tail calls that should be eliminated. Adding this attribute to the C code [successfully eliminates the tail call](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/a1jfqfej4). However, rustc currently has no equivalent attribute (although the `become` keyword is reserved for this purpose).

## Does it ever happen in Rust?

Okay, so it's not guaranteed. Can the compiler do it at all? Yes! Here's a function that computes Fibonacci numbers via a tail-recursive inner function:

```
pub fn fibonacci(n: u64) -> u64 {
    fn f(n: u64, a: u64, b: u64) -> u64 {
        match n {
            0 => a,
            _ => f(n - 1, a + b, a),
        }
    }
    f(n, 0, 1)
}
```

Not only is the tail call eliminated, the whole `fibonacci_lr` function is inlined into `fibonacci`, yielding only 12 instructions (and not a `call` in sight):

```
example::fibonacci:
        push    1
        pop     rdx
        xor     ecx, ecx
.LBB0_1:
        mov     rax, rdx
        test    rdi, rdi
        je      .LBB0_3
        dec     rdi
        add     rcx, rax
        mov     rdx, rcx
        mov     rcx, rax
        jmp     .LBB0_1
.LBB0_3:
        ret
```

If you [compare this to an equivalent `while` loop](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/mmmznd), the compiler generates *almost* the same assembly.

## What's the point?

You probably shouldn't be relying on optimizations to eliminate tail calls, either in Rust or in C. It's nice when it happens, but if you need to be sure that a function compiles into a tight loop, the surest way, at least for now, is to use a loop.

Answer (score 5):

There is a [tailcall](https://docs.rs/tailcall/latest/tailcall/) crate that you can use today and that adds a `#[tailcall]` annotation which forces tailcall optimized code generation.

There is also work to standardize explicit tailcalls [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/112788) and [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/3407).

Comment: This is an exciting development!